# jQuery AJAX. Return value is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have that code:

```
var s, d, p = '';

$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {action: "get_info"},
        success: function(r)
        {
            // r contain that json data
            // {"s":"long-string","d":"string","p":"string"}
            // That served from the server with that header
            //
            // header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
            // header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
            // header('Content-type: application/json');

            d = r.d;
            s = r.s;
            p = r.p;
        }
    }
);

// And here console return s as undefined
console.log(s);
```

Any idea on what's going wrong with that ?

Comment: Why don't you put `console.debug(r)` at the first point in the success callback and see what returns.

Comment: As an aside, did you know variables `s` and `d` will be undefined because of the way you've declared them? http://jsfiddle.net/beneverard/KdDVe/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$.ajax()` call simply starts the ajax operation. The code then falls through to your `console.log` statement but the ajax call hasn't returned yet. Hence the value of `s` has not yet been set.

At some point later the ajax call returns your results and at that point your call back is fired. So if you want to refer to the value that is returned, you should reference the variable `s` inside the callback.

The better way to do this is normally like this:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {action: "get_info"},
        success: function(r)
        {

            s = r.s;

            // Do something with s here...
        }
    }
);
```

If you really need to, you can reference `s` outside of the callback but if you do, you need to put some mechanism in place to make sure that `s` has already been initialised (i.e. that your ajax call has already returned). This introduces other complexities such as  synchronisation and error handling and can make your program flow rather unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because when you call `$.ajax(...);` it returns immediately. The `success` property specifies a callback that gets called when the AJAX request finishes, and `s` is only populated there; it's undefined before that.

So basically don't do anything with `s` before the `success` callback is launched.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you think the code executes in the way you have it laid out. It's actually symatically identical to:-

```
var s, d, p = '';
// And here console return s as undefined
console.log(s);
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {action: "get_info"},
        success: function(r)
        {
            // r contain that json data
            // {"s":"long-string","d":"string","p":"string"}
            // That served from the server with that header
            //
            // header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
            // header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
            // header('Content-type: application/json');

            d = r.d;
            s = r.s;
            p = r.p;
        }
    }
);
```

What you probably want is:-

```
var s, d, p = '';

$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {action: "get_info"},
        success: function(r)
        {
            // r contain that json data
            // {"s":"long-string","d":"string","p":"string"}
            // That served from the server with that header
            //
            // header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
            // header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
            // header('Content-type: application/json');

            d = r.d;
            s = r.s;
            p = r.p;
            // And here console return s as undefined
           console.log(s);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying data type Like 
           `type: "POST",
           url: ajaxurl,
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {action: "get_info"},`...