# jQuery Ajax results in undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, undefined, webmethod

I have a simple function which only returns a translated message from the server to the client. But the result shows undefined, when I pass the result into a var.

```
function MessageNoResult() {
  $.ajax(
  {
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/WebMethods.aspx/MessageNoResult") %>',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      return msg.d;
    }
  });
}
```

**Result --> Undefined (bad)**

```
var message = MessageNoResult();
alert(message);
```

When I look into the Headers it gives me:

```
Server  ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0
Date    Wed, 09 Nov 2011 09:01:31 GMT
X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
Cache-Control   private, max-age=0
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length  24
Connection  Close

Response {"d":"No search result"}
JSON d "No search result"
```

Why do I still get an undefined result?

Comment: you are trying to return from callback function. one of the ways is to do your code with response  in `success` block

Comment: what does the console say when you type `console.dir(msg)` within you `success: function(msg)`?

Comment: When I place the code into the success block, it works perfect. I was trying to make the code more reusable.

Comment: In that case you will need to place the logic which deals with your ajax response in its own function and call that from your success handler - see the answers from me and AndreasAL for how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a callback function to the `MessageNoResult` function

```
function MessageNoResult(callback) {
  $.ajax(
  {
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/WebMethods.aspx/MessageNoResult") %>',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      callback(msg);
    }
  });
}
```

And then call:

```
MessageNoResult(function(msg) {
    alert(msg.d);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The ajax call is still being executed as your code moves on to the `alert(message)` line, so the `message` variable has no value.

You need to pass the value of the response to a function within the `success` method.

```
success: function(msg) {
  myFunction(msg.d);
}

// outside ajax call
function myFunction(ajaxValue) {
    alert(ajaxValue)
}
```

Comment: There is no way to specifically set a variable, as you will still encounter the same problem where process flow will continue before your ajax has fully executed. You only real option if you don't want to place your code in the `success` method is to pass it across to another function - example amended.

Comment: Expanded Rory McCrossan's answer with a callback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062574/jquery-ajax-results-in-undefined/8062737#8062737

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call is an async call and you’re running the alert right after the MessageNoResult, thus the message has no value until you’ve actually completed the ajax request.

You’ll need to run your alert inside the success from ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return from success which is  a callback function. Set a global variable and use it within the success function `retmess = msg.d` to store the return or set the content of an html element `jQuery('#status').html(msg);`

Comment: This will give you the problem that you don't know when the value of  `retmess` gets set so you won't know whne you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
var message = MessageNoResult();
```

is setting the `message` variable to the return value of the `MessageNoResult` functiion. Since you have no return value in this function, you get `undefined` as response.

The corrcet way to handle this is by dealing with the return value from the Ajax call inside the `success` callback.

For a similar question see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887284/jquery-ajax-return-value-is-undefined/7887295#7887295):