# Ajax Handler callback function: response object is undefined

Tags: ajax

Good afternoon, I am having a issue with data not availble in my javascript call.

Case 1:

```
    function FirstFunction() {
           $.ajax({
            url: "abc.axd",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
             success: function (resp) {
                SecondFunction(resp);
            },
            error: function () { alert("Error Occured") }
        });
    }

    function SecondFunction(data) {
        alert("SecondFunction");
        alert(data.responseText);

    }
```

It triggeres second function but `alert(data.responseText)` is always `undefined`.

Case 2:

I tried it with `async: false`.

But still but `alert(data.responseText)` is undefined.

Case 3:

I have tried this one as well but still same issue,
[jQuery Ajax results in undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062574/jquery-ajax-results-in-undefined/8062737#8062737)

Can someone point me what's missing please?

Comment: Is my answer working?

Comment: just building the app.. let you know in a minute

Comment: Eagerly waiting... `:D`

Comment: I think with out using your answer, it already parsing it into JSON, hence getting below exception-Unexpected token o, which means it already available in JSON format. So its not working

Comment: What's the server's response, and what's the error in console?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 03 Jul 2015 12:54:32 GMT
Content-Length: 44

{"IsPackageStillAvailableForSamePrice":true}

Comment: Gotcha! Now try my updated answer!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82297/discussion-between-hari-gillala-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
alert(data.IsPackageStillAvailableForSamePrice);
```